# Existing modified entry get reinserted EF

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have two entities in many-to-many `Activity` and `History`

I am trying to add an existing modified `History` to a new `Actvity` but once `SaveChnages` is called `History` records gets treated as a new and reinserted.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

```
using (HistoryRepo posRepo = new HistoryRepo())
            {
                EF.Stock.History pos = posRepo.Get(p.Symbol);
                pos.SaleDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                pos.OrderGL = p.TotalGainLossDollar;
                pos.OrderGLPercent = p.TotalGainLossPercentage;
                pos.CANSLIMRecordClosed = Mapper.Map<EF.Stock.CANSLIMRecord>(Data.Where(x => x.Symbol == p.Symbol).Select(x => { x.Type = "closed"; return x; }).FirstOrDefault());

                histories.Add(posRepo.Update(pos)); //wrapper for _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified
            }
```

Then a little later on

```
 using (ActivityRepo repo = new ActivityRepo())
        {
            Activity act = new Activity();

            act.Histories = histories; //same collection from code snippet above
            act.ElapsedTime = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString("h'h 'm'm 's's'");

            act = repo.Insert(act);  //wrapper for _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added
            repo.Save(); //wrapper for _context.SaveChanges();
```

}

Comment: For the second `repo` the history objects are new, because they're not attached to its context.

Comment: @GertArnold Makes sense. So should `posRepo.Update(pos)` from the first snippet happen in a `for` loop somewhere in the second snippet. What's the best practice here?

Comment: Best practice. You want me to be honest? Remove the repository layer altogether and work with directly with a context and its `DbSet`s. I wonder if an `ActivityRepo` is supposed (or even able) to attach history entities, but yes, basically that's the idea.

Comment: Repo layer is there because 95% of this  application is much more RESful/APIish where repo reduces code duping quite a bit, so I just kinda fell into the same pattern here too. I can definitely see how in this case dealing straight with context makes more sense.